# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 Ubuntu 16.04 Setup issue

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Following 2 links to setup Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 in system.

First link [Hyperledger-fabric setup](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv.html)

After following commands

```
    cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/devenv
    vagrant up
    vagrant ssh
```

Followed [hypeledger latest setup docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build.html)

After using

```
    cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    make dist-clean all
```

An error occured...

> github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrocksdb collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Makefile:137: recipe for target 'build/bin/peer' failed make:
>   *** [build/bin/peer] Error 2

On Left side my vagrant is running and right side is my Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 Setup command make dist-clean all

[image]

To me this seems to be problem of rocksdb, how can I resolve this?

Comment: aside from my response below, are you running with a current vagrant environment? when you ran 'vagrant up' did it construct a new environment or did it restart an older one? If you want to build from source, then you may want to consider 'vagrant destroy' prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fond solution in one git hub link.
One can try to resolve this issue by using following commands-

```
    apt-get install librocksdb-dev
    apt-get install libsnappy-dev
    apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

After this rockdb error should not be there. Will post more if found any other error and there solutions too.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 can be installed without having to build from source. The project publishes stable Docker images and binaries for each release. This may be a better approach to [installing Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and its dependencies.

However, if you want to build from source, note that Vagrant is no longer needed. The build should be capable of running natively on most platforms (Mac, Windows and Ubuntu).

You will need the same [prerequisites](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html) as for the Getting Started approach above - Docker (preferably the latest release), Go (1.9.x), Python 2.7 and Node 6.9.x (note that we do not yet support Node 7.x).

Occasionally, it has been observed that a fresh build (make all) from scratch may occasionally fail. If so, try running (make all) again.

As for the rocksdb error, Fabric no longer has a dependency on rocksdb and uses leveldb instead. It is entirely likely that because the vagrant environment gets little use of late, that it is not current.

Comment: Didn't I mentioned that I was already following those docks that you referred. Please provide a different solution then I already been trying.

Comment: How come you shared just few links and answered  with same info provided in question and nothing new and still got votes up? Doesn't make sense.